# How to Solve: 'str' object has no attribute 'data_format' in keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to make a classifier which can classify cats and dogs using keras.
I am just trying to create the tensor data from images using **ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()** which are sorted and kept in the directories whose paths are given in train_path, test_path etc.

**Here is my code:**

```
import numpy as np

import keras

from keras import backend as K

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Activation



train_path = 'cats-and-dogs/train' test_path = 'cats-and-dogs/test' valid_path = 'cats-and-dogs/valid'

train_dir = 'cats-and-dogs/' test_dir = 'cats-and-dogs/' valid_dir = 'cats-and-dogs/'



train_batches = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(train_path, directory=train_dir, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=10)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(test_path, directory=test_dir, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=5)

valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(valid_path, directory=valid_dir, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=10)
```

**But I am getting the following error using python 3.5:**

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated
>   as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CNNFromScratch.py", line
>   29, in 
>       train_batches = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(train_path, directory=train_dir, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'],
>   batch_size=10)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py",
>   line 565, in flow_from_directory
>       data_format=self.data_format,
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data_format'

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `flow_from_directory` of `ImageDataGenerator` is not static. Therefore you first have to initialize an instance of class `ImageDataGenerator` and then call this method.

This should work:

```
import numpy as np

import keras

from keras import backend as K

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_path = 'cats-and-dogs/train'
test_path = 'cats-and-dogs/test'
valid_path = 'cats-and-dogs/valid'

my_generator = ImageDataGenerator()

train_batches = my_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=10)

test_batches = my_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=5)

valid_batches = my_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(200,200), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=10)
```

Check [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) for adding more parameters.